# Elegantly create reference vector for gnuplot vectorplot

Tags: gnuplot

Suppose that I have a gnuplot-script to create a vector plot, e.g., see below.

```
s=0.2
set terminal wxt persist
set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [-1:1]
set size ratio -1
set samples 10
set key outside 
plot '++' using 1:2:($2*s):(-$1*s) with vectors title "1 [m/s]"
```

As you can see, I rescale the components of the vector to make the vector plot look nice. Now, I want to create a reference vector, with given length, which I can plot outside of the domain. I am looking for an elegant solution, which does not rely on additional lines to plot and which preferably can be controlled as conveniently as `set colorbox` for example.

Comment: Whats wrong with `set arrow`?

Comment: @Christoph Why did I not think about that? Can you suggest a smart way for correct scaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set arrow` for this. In order to get the correct scaling, you can use for an arrow of length `1`

```
set arrow from graph 1.1,first -1 to graph 1.1, first 0
```

That uses the `first` y-axis for the vertical length. If you want to have the arrow definition at one point, you can always use `macros` to evaluate them:

```
set macros
myarrow = 'set arrow from graph 1.1,first -1 to graph 1.1, first 0'
... a lot of code ...
@myarrow
```

Comment: Thanks, with your code, I would have to set it to `from graph 1.1, first -1*s`. To have it more general might be easier than you think, by using appropriate variables before on scaling the vectors. Thanks again.